# One network handler class for multiple ViewControllers

Tags: swift, xcode, api, delegates, viewcontroller

I have an app which has 5 different view controllers, accessible by a UITabBar.

Each of these ViewControllers will access API Data through 5 different URLs taken from the same API source.

How can I re-use the below API request code so I do not have to re-type this block 5 times in my code? The below code is my current set-up and the delegate is the first view controller.

```swift
protocol ClubFixturesManagerDelegate {

    func didUpdateTable (club: [ClubData])
    func didFailWithError(error: Error) 
}


struct MyClubFixturesManager{

    let getclubListURL = "someURL"
    var delegate: ClubFixturesManagerDelegate?

    func getClubID(clubID: String){

        let getClubResultsURL = "someURL"
        performRequest(with: getClubResultsURL)

    }


    func performRequest(with urlString: String){

        if let url = URL(string: urlString){

            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.setValue("APIToken", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

            //create URL session
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

                if error != nil{
                    self.delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error!)
                    return
                }

                if let safeData = data {

                    if let clubResults = self.parseJSON(safeData){

                        self.delegate?.didUpdateTable(club: clubResults)

                    }

                }

            }

            task.resume()

        }

    }

    func parseJSON(_ teamData: Data) -> [ClubData]?{

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        do{

            var clubInfo: [ClubData] = []
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(ClubSeasonData.self, from: teamData)
            for entry in decodedData.matches{

                let updatedDate = ISO8601Converter.converter(for: entry.utcDate)

                let clubInstance = ClubData(utcDate: updatedDate, homeTeam: entry.homeTeam.name, awayTeam: entry.awayTeam.name, homeTeamScore: entry.score.fullTime.homeTeam ?? nil, awayTeamScore: entry.score.fullTime.awayTeam ?? nil)
                clubInfo.append(clubInstance)

            }

            return clubInfo

        }

        catch{

              print(error)

            }

            return nil

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a new instance of your api manager in your viewDidLoad and then assign the delegate and perform the request.
Something like this:

```swift
var apiManager: MyClubFixturesManager?

func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  apiManager = MyClubFixturesManager()
  apiManager.delegate = self // Assuming self conforms to ClubFixturesManagerDelegate protocol
  apiManager?.performRequest(with: "yourUrl")

}
```

---

As a side note I would make the delegate weak to avoid retain cycles and memory leak. 
You just need to do something like this:

```swift
weak var delegate: ClubFixturesManagerDelegate?
```

And to do so you would need to make the protocol class bound:

```swift
protocol ClubFixturesManagerDelegate: class {

    func didUpdateTable (club: [ClubData])
    func didFailWithError(error: Error) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your complete setup but I would suggest if you haven't already, savinging this MyClubFixturesManager struct within its own file.

Then adding "static" to each of its properties and functions.

```
static func performRequest(with urlString: String)
```

Then try calling this from each VC you have set up

```
MyClubFixturesManager.performRequest(with urlString: urlString)
```

Not sure how it would work with your delegates though. The other option is creating an instance of this struct within each of your VCs. Hope this leads you down the right path.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried using static however it wouldn't work with the delegates. I managed to get it to work with a new struct instance of the above and assign the URL based on which VC is selected through a new function.